# How to put an JsonArray in a JsonObject using createNestedArray() with ArduinoJson?

Tags: json, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to send JSON-data from an ESP32 via TCP to another client. This should happen repeatingly. The JSON-String contains an array. However, when I try to put an array in the JSON-document like in the [example](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/createnestedarray/) of the Arduino-documentation using the function createNestedArray(), it works for a few times until it starts creating empty arrays.

The minimal code is this:

```
#include "ArduinoJson.h"

StaticJsonDocument<3000> doc;
JsonObject root = doc.to<JsonObject>();

void insertJsonArray(JsonObject root) {
    JsonArray arr = root.createNestedArray("arrValues");
    arr.add(42);
    arr.add(77); 
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    insertJsonArray(root);

    // Print values
    serializeJsonPretty(root, Serial);

    // Print size of Json-Document
    Serial.print("Json-Size: ");
    Serial.println(root.memoryUsage());

    delay(250);
}
```

The output looks like expected for the first 92 iterations:

```
{
  "arrValues": [
    42,
    77
  ]
}
Json-Size: 48
```

But after that it only sends empty arrays:

```
{
  "arrValues": []
}
Json-Size: 16
```

Has anybody an idea why it suddenly stops working at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, before talking about the problem, let's talk the capacity (i.e. size) of the json object required. If you use [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/), The json object

```
{
  "arrValues": [
    42,
    77
  ]
}
```

would need about 58 bytes (with extra 10 bytes allocation for ESP32 as suggested by ArduinoJson Assistant), so  your allocation of 3000 bytes to the `doc` would waste of a lot memory, while 60 bytes would be sufficient for the purpose of your json object.

```
StaticJsonDocument<60> doc;
```

Now about the problem your described. You have a StaticJsonDocument `doc` of 3000 bytes, and you are constantly inserting an JsonArray `root` into the `doc`, this is like appending the `root` infinitely into the `doc`, so it will sooner or later overflow. I don't see any reason why you need to do that constantly, if you need to create a json object in a loop, move the declaration of `StaticJsonDocument` into your loop and create it when you need it.

```
void loop() {
    StaticJsonDocument<60> doc;
    JsonObject root = doc.to<JsonObject>();

    JsonArray arr = root.createNestedArray("arrValues");
    arr.add(42);
    arr.add(77); 
    ...
}
```

You can also use `DynamicJsonDocument` instead of `StaticJsonDocument`:

```
    // use ArduinoJson Assistant tool to get the capacity
    const size_t capacity = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(2) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(1) + 20;
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);
    JsonObject root = doc.to<JsonObject>();

    JsonArray arr = root.createNestedArray("arrValues");
    arr.add(42);
    arr.add(77);
```

ArduinoJson is a powerful library, but it requires a little bit better understanding of C++ capability in order to use it effectively, try to spend sometime to go through all the documentations.